# Flexbox align to right MANY items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Everybody knows how to align ONE item to right in flexbox. But how to align for example the two last elements to right and rest traditional to the left? Here I have an example. I want elements with class `.r` aligned to right of header menu.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    padding: 15px;
}

ul li {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;  
}

.r {
 margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li class="r">Login</li>
    <li class="r">Sign Up</li>
</ul>
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dwLHE/43/)

Please for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `margin-left: auto` only on the second-to-last flex item.

```css
.r {
  margin-left: auto;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  padding: 15px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Menu</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li class="r">Login</li>
  <li>Sign Up</li>
</ul>
```

[**revised fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwLHE/44/)

When a flex item has `margin-left: auto`, it pushes itself away from everything on its left, and shifts everything on its right along with it.

In your case, `margin-left: auto` makes sense for the second-to-last child. But it doesn't make sense for the last child.

Alternatively, you can use `margin-right: auto` on STUFF:

```css
li:nth-child(4) {
 margin-right: auto;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    padding: 15px;
}

ul li {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Login</li>
    <li >Sign Up</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Wrap the two links that you want to align to the right in a `ul` like this:

```
<ul class="r">
  <li>Login</li>
  <li>Sign Up</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dwLHE/45/

Comment: This is invalid. A `div` can't be a direct child of a `ul`

Comment: @MichaelCoker Should it be a UL then?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks for the heads up

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah a `ul` will work the same and is valid html.

Comment: An `<ul>` in a `<li>` like in [fiddle A](http://jsfiddle.net/dwLHE/48/), not directly `ul > ul` which is also invalid HTML ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dwLHE/46/))

Answer (score 0):

@Michael_B's solution is what I would use, but you can also use a pseudo element and the `order` attribute to wedge the pseudo element in your markup and set it to `flex-grow` to fill the space between the left and right sides.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    /* width: 100%; */
    height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    padding: 15px;
}
ul li {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.r {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>More</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li class="r">Login</li>
    <li class="r">Sign Up</li>
</ul>
```